# Function Defined in Static Library is not being found

Tags: c, makefile

I am having a problem finding a function called `get_offsets()` defined in `bam_sqlite.c`.

I create a static library with the following `Makefile`:

```
CC    = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -std=c99 -fPIC
INC := -Iinclude -I./ -I/gpfs/commons/home/knagdimov/temp/git/Rbamdb/htslib/ -I/gpfs/commons/home/knagdimov/temp/git/Rbamdb/lmdb/libraries/liblmdb/ -I/gpfs/commons/home/knagdimov/temp/git/Rbamdb/sqlite3/

all:

    @mkdir -p bin 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c bamdb.c -o bin/bamdb.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c src/bam_api.c -o bin/bam_api.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c src/bam_lmdb.c -o bin/bam_lmdb.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c src/bam_sqlite.c -o bin/bam_sqlite.o
    ar -rcs bin/libbamdb.a bin/bamdb.o bin/bam_api.o bin/bam_lmdb.o bin/bam_sqlite.o
```

Then, I run `nm libbamdb.a` and get the following output:

```
bam_sqlite.o 
000000000000067b T get_offsets
```

Thus, the function is defined in the static library. Finally, I run another Makefile (in a higher directory) which contains the following:

```
PKG_BASE = $(shell pwd)/../
LIB_BASE = -Wl,-rpath,$(PKG_BASE)
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I$(PKG_BASE)bamdb -I$(PKG_BASE)Rbamdb -I$(PKG_BASE)bamdb/include/ -I$(PKG_BASE)htslib/ -I$(PKG_BASE)lmdb/libraries/liblmdb/ -I$(PKG_BASE)sqlite3/
PKG_CXXFLAGS = -I$(PKG_BASE)badb -I$(PKG_BASE)Rbamdb -I$(PKG_BASE)bamdb/include/ -I$(PKG_BASE)htslib/ -I$(PKG_BASE)lmdb/libraries/liblmdb/ -I$(PKG_BASE)sqlite3/
PKG_LIBS = -L$(PKG_BASE)/ -L$(PKG_BASE)/bamdb/bin/ -L$(PKG_BASE)htslib/ -L$(PKG_BASE)lmdb/libraries/liblmdb/ -L$(PKG_BASE)sqlite3/ -lbamdb -lhts -llmdb -lsqlite3
```

The other libraries are libsqlite3.so, libhts.a, liblmdb.a, and they seem to all be found. The only one not being found is libbamdb.a which makes me believe I am defining the static library in a wrong way.

**Please note that bamdb source code (bam_api.c, bam_lmdb.c, bam_sqlite.c, bam_sqlite.c) depend on functions defined in other static libraries. Should I include them them I'm compiling these source codes into object files?**

Ultimately the following solved the problem: the Makevars file is creating a .so file using the g++ compiler. The previous libraries were C libraries compiled using gcc. The header files of the C source code didn't include the following:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 
 extern "C" { 
 #endif 
 #ifdef __cplusplus
}
```

Including that solved the problem.

Comment: Post the whole makefile

Comment: @NeilButterworth that is the entirety of the Makefile for the root directory. Do you want to see the Makefiles for bamdb, htslib, lmdb, or sqlite3?

Comment: I'm sure you've heard of [minimal complete examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Try writing code that links to `libbamdb.a`, and no other library. Show us the command that Make executes. Try that command from the command line. *Simplify.*

Comment: Unless I am missing something, there are no targets in the code you posted, so I don't see how that is a valid makefile.

Comment: have you tried to find other functions defined in `bam_sqlite.c`?

Comment: @StephanLechner thanks for that advice. I defined a simple ```print_bam_sqlite()``` function in ```bam_sqlite.c``` and that can't be found.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I included the rest of the Makefile for bamdb. These source codes depends on code defined in other static libraries. Should I include them during compilation of the bamdb source code into object files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using gcc and the gnu linker, then this description of the -l command line argument may help

> The linker will search an archive only once, at the location where it
>   is specified on the command line. If the archive defines a symbol
>   which was undefined in some object which appeared before the archive
>   on the command line, the linker will include the appropriate file(s)
>   from the archive. However, an undefined symbol in an object appearing
>   later on the command line will not cause the linker to search the
>   archive again.
>
> See the -( option for a way to force the linker to search archives
>   multiple times.

So if the reference to get_offsets() is coming from one of the -l library after -lbamdb then you need to rearrange the -l or use -( -) .

Comment: how would I go about doing that, specifically? Would the following work:     ```PKG_LIBS = -L$(PKG_BASE)/ -L$(PKG_BASE)/bamdb/bin/ -L$(PKG_BASE)htslib/ -L$(PKG_BASE)lmdb/libraries/liblmdb/ -L$(PKG_BASE)sqlite3/ -Wl, --start-group -lbamdb -lhts -llmdb -lsqlite3 -Wl, --end-group
```